# Text shown in single line in notepad

Tags: c#

I am having issue with a regular notepad.

If I open a file in wordpad, it displays text from a rich textbox correctly (with the line breaks from the textbox). But in notepad it's just one huge line, how can I get to so that when writing into a file, it recognizes the linebreaks in the rich text box?

What I do is open up a notepad file that contains a block of text and goes into richtextBox1.

Copy text from first text box and write in richTextBox2 the text from the first richtextbox and the copied text with stripped vowels (copytext) as well as write into the second notepad file (_Parsed.text).

```
string Chosen_File = "C:\\_Testfile.txt";
string Second_File = "C:\\_Parsed.txt";
string wholeText = "";

private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        //Add data from text file to rich text box
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        //Read lines of text in text file                
        string textLine = "";

        StreamReader txtReader;
        txtReader = new StreamReader(Chosen_File);

        do {
            textLine = textLine + txtReader.ReadLine() + " ";
        }

        //Read line until there is no more characters
        while (txtReader.Peek() != -1);

        richTextBox1.Text = textLine;

        txtReader.Close();
    }

}

private void Write(string file, string text) {

    //Check to see if _Parsed File exists

        //Write to _Parsed text file
        using(StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(file)) {
            objWriter.Write(text);
            objWriter.Close();
    } 

}

private void newSummaryMethod(string copyText) {

    //Write into richTextBox2 all relevant text
    copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + copyText
    Write(Second_File, wholeText);
}


private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        newSummaryMethod(copyText);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show where in that big code block the problem resides...

Comment: You're not using your nl variable

Comment: I have edited my question after thinking I know what the issue is.

Comment: and you don't show where are you calling the Write method...

Comment: Sorry, got rid of it when I was trying to shorten the code for the question. I have included it in the newSummaryMethod();

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to separate Data and Presentation.

If you have a file with lines in it you can read it with [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("file1.txt");
```

After that you can show all the lines on your textbox, console whatever else.

When you're appending text, just update your lines collection

```
lines.AddRange(secondListOfLines);
```

And save the updated file using [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
File.WriteAllLines(lines, "file2.txt");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it when using StreamReader and StreamWriter? I'm not quite sure how to implement your suggestion in my code.

Comment: Have a look at he examples here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried to look at the example but it's not happy with WriteAllLines. Do you know a way with the streamWriter and streamReader? I will make myself an application so I can learn how to do it the way you've done it but at mean time with time running out for this last little thing, I just need a fix in my code with what I've got.